# Рекурсивный проход по элементам XML

Tags: c++, xml

Я выбрал `tinyxml2` для парсинга XML файлов, хочу узнать как рекурсивно обойти элементы XML.

**text.XML**

```
<data>
    <data>
        <username>johny1994</username>
        <realname>John Batcher</realname>
    </data>
    <data>
        <username>drdre222</username>
        <realname>Doctor Dree</realname>
    </data>
</data>
```

`data` - первый XML элемент, за ним следует дочерний `data` элемент, за дочерним `data` следуют дочерние `username` и `realname`.
Дочерних `data` которые идут от корневого отца элемента `data` может быть N количество (в моем случае 2). Нужно найти все эти дочерние `data` элементы и пройтись по ним рекурсивно.

Код:

```
tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
tinyxml2::XMLError e = doc.LoadFile("text.xml");
if (e != tinyxml2::XML_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "Error load file" << std::endl;
}

auto root = doc.FirstChildElement("data");
if (root == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Child element not found\n";
}

// Тут должен быть какой-то код типа цикла для обработка data элементов
// что-то типа for (root; root < elementCount; ++root) {};
auto rootdata = root->FirstChildElement("data");
if (rootdata == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Child (data) element not found\n" << std::endl;
}

auto username = rootdata->FirstChildElement("username");
if (username == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "username is null ptr" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Username:\t" << username->GetText() << std::endl;

auto realname = rootdata->FirstChildElement("username");
if (realname == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "realname is null ptr" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Real name:\t" << realname->GetText() << std::endl;
```

Вывод должен быть примерно следующим:

```
Username: johny1994
Real name: John Batcher
Username: drdre222
Real name: Doctor Dre
```

Comment: Наверное вам больше подойдет SAX парсер.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно рекурсию используют для продвижения вглубь дерева (от корня к листам). Не понимаю, зачем Вам рекурсивно пробегать по элементам одного уровня, по которым гораздо удобнее пройтись циклом:

```
auto root = doc.FirstChildElement("data");
if (root == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Child element not found\n";
}

// Тут должен быть какой-то код типа цикла для обработка data элементов
auto current_data = root->FirstChildElement("data");
auto last_data = root->LastChildElement("data");
do
{
    if (current_data == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Child (data) element not found\n" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    auto username = current_data->FirstChildElement("username");
    if (username == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "username is null ptr" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Username:\t" << username->GetText() << std::endl;

    auto realname = current_data->FirstChildElement("username");
    if (realname == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "realname is null ptr" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "Real name:\t" << realname->GetText() << std::endl;

    current_data = current_data->NextSibling();
}
while(current_data != last_data);
```

вот пример рекурсии:

```
void Recursion(const XMLNode* root, const XMLNode* current_data)
{

    if (current_data == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Child (data) element not found\n" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    auto username = current_data->FirstChildElement("username");
    if (username == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "username is null ptr" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Username:\t" << username->GetText() << std::endl;

    auto realname = current_data->FirstChildElement("username");
    if (realname == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "realname is null ptr" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Real name:\t" << realname->GetText() << std::endl;

    current_data = current_data->NextSibling();

    if(current_data != root->LastChildElement("data"))
    {
        Recursion(root, current_data->NextSibling());
    }
}
```